# Thread sleep is freezing my code. Java client-Server communication

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I wrote a program that creates a communication with sockets between two computers. Currently the program makes the server send numbers from 1 to 50 to the client.

When I run this program the outputs via the console appear way too fast so I would like to make the message sender thread to sleep for a second. However when I write the try catch to make the thread sleep the whole program stops. What am I doing wrong?

Server side:

```
public class ControladorClientes extends Thread{
    public Socket s;
    private OutputStreamWriter osw;
    public InputStreamReader isr;
            
    public ControladorClientes(Socket s) {
        try {
            this.s = s;
            this.osw = new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            this.isr = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
            
        }catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Thread tWriter = new ServerWriter(osw);
        tWriter.start();

    }
}
```

ServerWriter:

```
public class ServerWriter extends Thread{
    OutputStreamWriter osw;
    
    public ServerWriter(OutputStreamWriter osw) {
        this.osw = osw;
    }
        
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int n = 1;
        boolean active = true;
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
        while(active) {
            try {
                bw.write("Server: " + Integer.toString(n));
                bw.newLine();
                n++;
                if(n==50) n = 1;
                try{Thread.sleep(100);}catch(InterruptedException ex){ex.printStackTrace();;}
            }catch(IOException e) {
                try {
                    active = false;
                    if(bw != null) bw.close();
                }catch(IOException f) {e.printStackTrace();f.printStackTrace();}
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class SimpleClient {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 5555);
            
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
            Thread tReader = new ClientReader(isr);
            tReader.start();
        }catch(IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

And the ClientReader:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ClientReader extends Thread {
    InputStreamReader isr;
    public ClientReader(InputStreamReader isr) {
        this.isr = isr;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        while(true) {
            try {
                String msg = br.readLine();
                System.out.println(msg);
            } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();break;}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `bw.flus()` seems to solve all my problems.